# Obspy.read() not working when called from mod_python apache module

Tags: python, apache, web-services, obspy

I'm trying to make a simple web service which reads an MSEED file and outputs some information on that.

The most reasonable choice seemed to be using [python](http://www.python.org/) with the excellent [obspy](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki) module (A Python Toolbox for seismology/seismological observatories), which is widely used in the seismological community.

I succed in reading a file and getting some information from it with this simple python code:

```
import obspy
import numpy
import sys


my_filename = "SOME FILE"
my_start_time =  "2012-01-01T08:00:00"
my_end_time =  "2012-01-01T09:00:00"

dt = obspy.UTCDateTime(my_start_time)
et = obspy.UTCDateTime(my_end_time)
st = obspy.read(my_filename, starttime=dt, endtime=et)
....then do something....
```

Now, if I want to implement it as a web service, among the several different choiche I can install the mod_python on Apache, and invoke such script in a bit different way.

I do as follows (the script is in  a file called `test.py`):

```
from mod_python import util
import obspy
import numpy
import sys

def index(req):
    [...]
    startdate="2012-01-01T08:00:01"
    enddate="2012-01-01T08:10:00"
    myfilename=" SOME FILE"
    dt = obspy.UTCDateTime(startdate)
    et = obspy.UTCDateTime(enddate)

    ##### read file
    st = obspy.read(my_filename, starttime=dt, endtime=et) ******
    [...]
```

**What happens is that on the last line it hangs without giving any error.**
when invoking the script from my server
    http://localhost.my/cgi-bin/test.py 
it works well until the last line, then after that it doesn't even print anything but, again **WITHOUT OUTPUT ERRORS**

Eveno more weird, if I change the last line with

```
st = obspy.read(my_filename, headonly=True)
```

then it works.

**What I tried:**

1. Changing permission to files/folders. The script and the file are in my /var/www/cgi-bin directory. Assigning readable to everyone to files and directory did not work
2. moving files to different folders
3. changing the owner of the file/dir (to www-data)

But it still doesn't work.

I don't understand if it is a problem of the obspy module or some limitation to the apache mod_python.

Any idea about how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best answer I received from obspy [github issue page](https://github.com/obspy/obspy/issues/572) was the following

> It seems to be related to a memory allocation issue. You could try to
>   update to the latest ObsPy repository version as we recently made some
>   changes to that and see if that resolves your issue. I am pretty sure
>   that it is not a permissions related issue.
>
> Otherwise, if you are not tied to using mod_python, you could try out
>   one of the very many and oftentimes very good Python web frameworks.
>   If you just need it for a simple webservice, a microframework might
>   suit you well:
>
> http://flask.pocoo.org/ http://www.pylonsproject.org/
>   http://www.cherrypy.org/ Of course Django might also appeal to you.
>
> Cheers!